# SEO - Need full path url on link for multiple subdomain site?

Tags: seo

My site has different language and I plan to have subdomain like en.domain.com, cht.domain.com,
chs.domain.com then inside the site all other links i will have like href='/music', etc. as it will work for all subdomains.

Will it be confusing for seo to index my site? Do I need to dynamically set the full path for each subdomains?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The drawback of your method it that you will have to create one sitemap for each subdomain and post it in each subdomain, which can be tedious if you have many subdomains. You would need to maintain several Google Webmaster Tools account too to monitor them too. Maintaining several subdomains is not very efficient SEO-wise.

Another method is to use folders, such as `domain.com/en`, `domain.com/cht`, `domain.com/chs`, etc... You would only need to maintain one sitemap and one Google Webmaster Tool account, which is less hassle. It would also be much more efficient regarding SEO and rankings.

No matter which method you choose, it is highly recommended to use the `rel="alternate" hreflang="x"` tags to notify existing page translations. This is very good for indexing, it helps search engines a lot.

Comment: Good answer. Just to add it is possible to manage international domains/href-lang tags inside Google Webmaster Tools as of very recently. This can help debug any issues or missing tags.

Comment: There's a problem in my case. I've some section product review that I will only show in english(no resources for other language) but I want to make it visible to other languages which means people who go to domain.com/cht they will see a product section in english. I was using subdomains because if the content I show in english then I will just use the en.domain.com. But it will be complicated because once they are back to english I will need cookie to remember to show them cht or chs for multilanguage content. What do you think it's best for me?

Comment: Don't publish any content in domain.com/cht if it is not written in cht. If you want to display the english version in the mean time when users go to domain.com/cht, use a redirect to the corresponding page on domain.com/en. Once the translation is available, publish it on /cht and remove the redirect.

Comment: That will be the same if I just have the url as /en if the page display in english?

Comment: That is up to you, if you want to put English pages under the root (i.e. domain.com/mypage.html) why not, but I would put them under domain.com/en/mypage.html because I think it is better organization. No matter what you choose, one choice is not better than the other when it comes to SEO in this case.